# Replace License header in History with BFG

Tags: java, git, bfg-repo-cleaner

Is there a way to replace the license header in Git history using [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/):
In my code I have this header in Java files:

```
/*
 * MyCompany, Platform for Something Good
 * Copyright 2019-present, MyCompany, and individual contributors
 * as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
 * distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
 *
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
 * Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
 * 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
 *
 * Other licenses:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Commercial licenses for this work are available. These replace the above
 * GPL 3.0 and offer limited warranties, support, maintenance, and commercial
 * deployments.
 *
 * For more information, please email: me@mycompany.com
 *
 */
```

I need this header to be replaced with another license header in Git history for all Java files, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately BFG Repo Cleaner doesn't support multi-line replacements. creating many 1-line replacements may work for you, but may cause funny issues.

See:

- https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/58